# Can this SELECT be improved?

Tags: sql, oracle

I found this legacy SELECT statement which is performing very poorly. Column ID is not a PK.
How can I improve it?
Is subquery AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT... really needed?

```
SELECT A.JOB,
 MIN(A.ID) AS START_ID,
 MAX(A.ID) AS END_ID,
 COUNT(DISTINCT A.R) AS CNT
  FROM (SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(copyfrom 20) PARALLEL(copyto 20) */
             COPYTO.ID,
             COPYTO.ROWID AS R,
             TRUNC((DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COPYTO.ID) - 1) / 500000) AS JOB
              FROM T1 COPYFROM
              JOIN T2 COPYTO
                ON COPYFROM.ID = COPYTO.ID
             WHERE COPYTO.DATE IS NULL
               AND COPYFROM.DATE IS NOT NULL
               AND NOT EXISTS
             (SELECT * FROM T1 COPYFROM
                     WHERE COPYFROM.ID = COPYTO.ID
                       AND COPYFROM.DATE IS NULL)) A
 WHERE A.JOB < 1
 GROUP BY A.JOB
```

There are indices on T1 and T2:

```
create index idx1 on t1 (id, date);
create index idx2 on t2 (id, date);
```

I would like to upload the execution plan but don't know how?

Comment: That correlated subquery seems odd for two reasons: 1) Given the where condition `AND COPYFROM.DATE IS NOT NULL` there should already be no `COPYFROM` records with the `COPYTO.ID` that is NULL, making the correlated subquery superfluous. 2) The alias for the `T1` table in the correlated subquery matches the alias for the query in which it's contained which could lead to a cartesian product (wrong results and possible a crazy large intermediate result set and runtime).

Comment: @JNevill I don't think the correlated subquery is superfluous - the main query is selecting records from copyfrom that have a non-null date and for whose ID no *other* row exists whose date is null

Comment: We need more information. A column named `ID` should be the table's unique key. But the query seems to assume to find multiple t1 rows for the same ID. So, is `ID` unique in t1 and/or t2? What makes you say this is the worst query you have seen so far? Not considering the ID thing, it looks okay to me. This is just gathering the rows to process, building jobs of 500k IDs, and giving information on the content of the first job. If you remove the `WHERE` clause, you get the information on all jobs.

Comment: Hmmm... you're right. ID is not a PK. T1 has 2 columns as PK (ID + something) and T2 has 4 columns as a PK (ID + 3 cols). Would it speed up this query if I would add a unique key instead of a current PK and then add a new autogenerated PK using only 1 column?

Comment: No, composite keys are no problem. The name `ID` is just misleading for the human reader of the query.

Comment: Nobody can tune a query just be looking at the SQL. It's all about the data in your tables, the cardinality relationships between them, and the execution plan Oracle is using based on the statistics it has. Every SQL no matter how written could perform acceptably given the data, and even SQL that looks extremely well written can perform poorly given the data. The only thing folks can do with a SQL all by itself is wildly guess, and most often the guesses will be incorrect, because they don't know your data or see the execution plan.

Comment: @PaulW "Nobody can tune a query just be looking at the SQL..." -- That's so true.

Comment: Although if you format it neatly and lose the caps lock it will be easier to tell what it's trying to do. It's actually not so terrible - it's joining two tables, applying a "not exists" condition, then filtering on the analytic rank expression and aggregating the results.  It's not helpful that there are two "COPYFROM"s but I'd expect the normal precedence rules to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the query is already using windowing functions, there's really no need to use a correlated subquery - you should be able to achieve the same result with another windowing function (untested):

```
SELECT A.JOB,
 MIN(A.ID) AS START_ID,
 MAX(A.ID) AS END_ID,
 COUNT(DISTINCT A.R) AS CNT
  FROM (SELECT COPYTO.ID,
             COPYTO.ROWID AS R,
             COPYFROM.DATE as COPYFROM_DATE,
             TRUNC((DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COPYTO.ID) - 1) / 500000) AS JOB,
             COUNT(CASE 
                     WHEN COPYFROM.DATE IS NULL THEN 1 
                     ELSE NULL 
                   END) OVER (PARTITION BY COPYTO.ID) AS CNT_NULL_DATES_FOR_THIS_ID
              FROM T1 COPYFROM
              JOIN T2 COPYTO
                ON COPYFROM.ID = COPYTO.ID
             WHERE COPYTO.DATE IS NULL                   
) A
 WHERE A.JOB < 1
   AND A.CNT_NULL_DATES_FOR_THIS_ID = 0
   AND A.COPYFROM_DATE IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY A.JOB
```

*UPDATE* As pointed out by @astentx in their comment, the `COUNT(...)` didn't work as intended because of the `WHERE ... COPYFROM.DATE IS NOT NULL`. I modified the query accordingly (moved the WHERE clause to the outer SELECT)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e696d/1)

Comment: `WHEN COPYFROM.DATE IS NULL THEN 1` will never be encountered  because of `WHERE ... AND COPYFROM.DATE IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @astentx You're absolutely right. I've fixed it.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt are you sure? Now I am confused because previous version of your SELECT seems to worked just fine (the same as original just much much faster) but this SELECT doesn't select anything in my case.

Comment: @DaniChe For my (very limited) test data, the fixed version worked as expected - see the SQL fiddle that's linked in my answer. However, I might have misunderstood your intent - if that's the case, please edit the question and add example data and expected output.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Thank you very much for your help. Much much appreciated. I am now trying to investigate why your new SELECT doesn't work for me... very confused...

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I figured it out why your SQL doesn't work on my real data in my DB. Your SQL returns 10 as JOB value, but original query returns 0. Is it possible somehow to adapt your SQL to return 0?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Your SELECT works if I remove "WHERE A.JOB < 1" but then it returns 10 for JOB instead of 0 as original SELECT did

Answer (score 1):

Having learned from the request comments that the columns called `ID` are not unique in either table, the query looks good.

You want to find copyfrom rows with a date and copyto rows without a date. For this I'd suggest the following indexes:

```
create index idx1 on t1 (date, id);
create index idx2 on t2 (date, id);
```

Then the query checks whether there is a copyfrom row without a date for an ID, so another index could come into play:

```
create index idx3 on t1 (id, date);
```

That's about it. Even better might be to partition the tables into two partitions each, one for null dates, one for non-null dates.

Comment: Hmmm... I already have indices:

`create index idx1 on t1 (id, date);
create index idx2 on t2 (id, date);`

would I benefit from creating those indices:

`create index idx3 on t1 (date, id);
create index idx4 on t2 (date, id);`

?

Comment: Yes, these indexes can help. With an index that starts with the date, you can easily find all rows where the date is null. You can also find all rows where the date is not null with such an index. Whether these indexes get used is another question, though. The DBMS will estimate what percentage of rows it may have to access. If these are too many, using an index is too costly. Well, you can just try the indexes and see whether they get used and whether this speeds up your query. Anyway, partitioning by null/not null should be an even better solution.